# Using shap to assess the effects of variables/parameters in explicit mathematical expressions

Tags: python, machine-learning, differential-equations, shap

I am currently trying to learn [`shap`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). When I go through the [linear regression](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/overviews/An%20introduction%20to%20explainable%20AI%20with%20Shapley%20values.html#Explaining-a-linear-regression-model) example, a problem came across to me:

since the linear regression model can be explicitly expressed in [algebraic forms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html), does this mean that `shap` can be used for assessing the effects of variables/parameters in (some) mathematical expressions?

For example, we could use some methods, like [deep symbolic regression method](https://github.com/brendenpetersen/deep-symbolic-optimization), to extract mathematical expressions from data, is that meaningful to further apply `shap` to the obtained expressions?

If so, could we use `shap` to explore the effects of some coefficients/parameters in the non-linear partial differential equations?

Sorry if I made some mistakes.

Best

Answer (score 0):

To caricature what SHAP is, it is showing partial derivative of output with respect to input.
Which tells you, numerically, and specifically to one input (it is not a general "explanation" of the model; it is a local "explanation") which input variables are the most decisive.

Said otherwise, it answer the question "if that input had been different, would that change a lot the output".

So, that is a attempt to get an explanation when we can't understand what the model does otherwise. SHAP interest is for opaque models. It is a tool to help understand what it does. And it does so locally (for some entry, it is other input variables that are the most decisive).

For example, if your model predict y=1/(x₁-1) + tan(x₂), then for (x₁,x₂)=(0.99, π/4), x₁ is way more sensitive than x₂. Add 0.02 to x₁, and result is totally different. Add 0.02 to x₂, and nothing major happens.
For (x₁,x₂)=(½, π/2-0.01), it is the opposite.

SHAP is a way to tell you that. Which seems easy in a case where I can explicitly describe the model, but it is used for models that are so complex and convoluted, that nothing obvious can be said.

But for a linear model, what could SHAP say that you don't already know just by looking the model ?
Importance of each variable is already known, and not just locally: they are the coefficient of your linear model.

For symbolic model, it is less obvious, but the point of using symbolic regression is to have a formal model, and to understand it directly. Not to study it numerically on examples and approximations.

So, you are trying to apply SHAP to cases that are the oppositive of what SHAP was invented for. The very reason why SHAP exists, is precisely because deep learning models do not provide understandable models, like formal ones, or like linear regression.

Understand that the part of the documentation you quoted are pedagogical parts. They don't show how to use SHAP on linear regression because it is a good idea. They show it because it is easier to understand how "explanation" works on an example where we already perfectly know the explanation.

It is a little bit  like those examples that train a model from a dataset made of `x=(x₁, x₂), y=x₁*x₂`, to train a neural network to multiply two numbers. They don't do so because it is a good idea. You obviously don't need a neural network to perform a multiplication! They do so because it is a good example: you know perfectly what result are expected without long explanation, so you can easily judge how the example works well; plus it is not linear, so it shows the ability of NN to build operations that are not linear combination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am a little confused about "They don't show how to use SHAP on linear regression because it is a good idea". What do you mean here? (I guess that you mean it is not a good idea). Another issue is that in the [linear regression tutorial](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/overviews/An%20introduction%20to%20explainable%20AI%20with%20Shapley%20values.html), the author said "This means that the magnitude of a coefficient is not necessarily a good measure of a feature’s importance in a linear model." How do you think about that?